# php regex replace caracters from filename until extension

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace all characters except `'A-Z','a-z','0-9', '_', '-', '(', ')'` from a filename, until the extension.

For the moment i have:

```
$filename = '23$%^&.234234.%^.234$%$#)(.^$.png';

$fileName = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9_\-\(\) ]/', '-', $filename);
```

and i get

```
$filename : 23------234234----234----)(----png
```

The problem is that the '.' from extension is removed.
The filename can have different extension.

How should i make to change the characters, but not the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/pathinfo) function to separate extension from filename and replace unwanted character only in base filename. After everything, just merge those parts:

```
$filename = '23$%^&.234234.%^.234$%$#)(.^$.png';
$pathinfo = pathinfo($filename);
$filename = implode('.', array(
  preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9_\-\(\) ]/', '-', $pathinfo['filename']),
  $pathinfo['extension']
));

var_dump($filename);
```

Output:

```
string '23-----234234----234----)(---.png' (length=33)
```

Comment: +1... but let's let him know that (as you know) `/[^A-Za-z0-9_\-\(\) ]/` can be compressed to a tidy `~[^\w() -]i~`  :)